# Do not come coins for a long time

Tags: transactions, ether, wallets

It took more than 18 hours of transfer ETH with exchange Binance on Stocks.Exchange. Although Etherscan confirms the success of the coins in your wallet. Support StocksExchenge not responding. Here's the transaction number: 0xeea6ab9b6dda5e6329136c8cc52b81851e1d004ff38e162d197e91fc50cd23d2 What to do? Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing else you can do but wait for the response from the exchange's support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, exchanges wait for 30 confirmations till they confirm a transaction. Additionally, some of them wait for confirmation from both C++ and Go implementation of Ethereum.

However, as for now, because there are [4302](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xeea6ab9b6dda5e6329136c8cc52b81851e1d004ff38e162d197e91fc50cd23d2) confirmations on your transaction and its increasing, you have to check with stocks.exchange. If they did not show your balance. You have to open a support ticket at there site.

Comment: The caliper does not respond...

Comment: Sorry that the answer is: they are the only one who can help you. Call there phone if they have, post on their facebook group if they have, mention then in twitter... This is if they did not respond after 3 days or 1 week for example. Best wishes, 

Please, if you find my answer is the best answer that you can find, then mark it as answer and vote up :)